# Second cohomology of cyclic groups, reference request

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $M$ be a $G$ module.
Denote by $M^G$ the set of elements in M which are invariant under the $G$-action. Consider the trace map $Tr:M\rightarrow M$ defined by
$$m\mapsto\sum_{g\in G} g(m).$$

A known result which I am looking reference for saying that if $G$ is cyclic group then
$$H^2(G,M)\cong M^G/\text{Im}(Tr(M)).$$

I was told that it suppose to be in any cohomology book, but I didn't found such reference.
I hope someone here might know where to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By definition $H^0(G,M) = M^G/{\rm Im}({\rm Tr}(M))$. the result you are looking for is that cyclic groups have periodic cohomology, with period $2$.

Comment: For references see [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44494/finite-groups-with-periodic-cohomology). In particular, Cartan - Eilenberg's Homological Algebra, and other books on homological algebra,e.g., C. Weibel.